# How do I pass current User and inputText value to Java-Controller?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-security, xhtml

I have a spring project with Primefaces. What I want to do is, to force password change on initial-login.

I created an xhtml-page which checks if the password equals the standard-password, if so than the user gets redirected to a passwordChange-form.

**Below the Form-Content**

```
<p:password id="password" name="password" placeholder="New Password"/>
<p:password id="passwordConfirm"  placeholder="Password Confirmations"/>
<p:commandButton action="#{parentEditController.doChangePassword()}" icon="ui-icon-refresh" 
                 title="Change Password" oncomplete="/secured/welcome.xhtml"/>
```

How do I get the password string to the `doChangePassword()` in my UserController? The `doChangePassword()`-method calls `userService.changePassword(password)`-method in which the password string is set as password for the current user and gets stored to DB via `userRepository.save(user)`.

My main problem is to get the password string to my controller so I'm able to pass it as string to the `userService.changePassword(String: password)`.

Hope anyone can help me?

Comment: Whats the issue? Just populate the form on passwordChange-form page, and submit that data to your controller directing to doChangePassword method.

Comment: `<p:commandButton action="#{UserController.doChangePassword()}" icon="ui-icon-refresh" title="Change Password" oncomplete="/secured/welcome.xhtml">` thats my submit-button, but error is always the same "NullPointerxception"